# Why is my code not returning the right value?

Tags: python

I was hoping my code would output what was left in stock but when I run my code I get this output instead: `<function get_sizes_in_stock at 0x10572f158>`

```
import select

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import random

session = requests.session()


def get_sizes_in_stock():
    global session
    endpoint = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/v4j0kn2qc/vtl376a1b'
    response = session.get(endpoint)

    soup = bs(response.txt, 'html.parser')

    div = soup.find("select", {"name": "s"})
    div = soup.find("select", {"name": "s"})
    all_sizes = select.find_all("option")

    sizes_in_stock = []
    for size in all_sizes:
        if "false" not in size["class"]:
            size_id = size["value"]
        sizes_in_stock.append(size_id.split("_")[1])

    return sizes_in_stock


print(get_sizes_in_stock)
```

I'm hoping for the code to output what's left in stock. Should output Medium, and Large

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `print(get_sizes_in_stock())`, not `print(get_sizes_in_stock)`. `get_sizes_in_stock` returns the function object, while `get_sizes_in_stock()` calls the function without any argument.

Answer (score 0):

All methods are objects in python.

```
print(get_sizes_in_stock)
```

returns the function object. I think you meant to call the function instead:

```
print(get_sizes_in_stock())
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. After making that fix it's still returning the wrong value. I'm now getting a [] return, instead of printing(get_sizes_in_stock). Thoughts?